# Displaying Timed Message Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subroutine that makes the message-box disappear after certain amount of time. The Sub works fine on it's own.

```
Sub MessageBoxTimer()
    Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 10
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Click OK (this window closes automatically after 10 seconds).", _
    AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
        Case 1, -1
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

When I implement this into my code which btw checks if used workbook is an up to date version of the workbook the desired message shows up but there's no time delay. Any Ideas why ?

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyPath As Workbook
    Dim WorkbookType As Range
    Dim Version As Long
    Dim CurrentVersion As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Version = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Ver").Value
    WorkbookType = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Typ").Value

    Set MyPath = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://LocationOfTheMasterSpreadsheet.xlsm", _
                               ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)

    Set SearchRange = MyPath.Worksheets("Master").Range("Type")
    Set WorkbookType = SearchRange.Find(What:=WorkbookType, _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'Conditions 
    If WorkbookType Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No such data found"
    Else
        CurrentVersion = WorkbookType.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If CurrentVersion = Version Then
            AckTime = 1
            Select Case InfoBox.Popup("This is a current version.", _
            AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
            Case 1, -1
            End Select
            Workbooks("MasterExcel.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False
        ElseIf CurrentVersion <> Version Then
            AckTime = 1
            Select Case InfoBox.Popup("This is NOT a current version.", _
            AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
            Case 1, -1
            End Select
            Workbooks("MasterExcel.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The msg is supposed to show up immediately, right? Is the problem, that it doesn't go away? Or goes away right away? To get the second code to work I had to add `Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` otherwise it wouldn't run at all so I feel like I'm missing something here

Comment: This method is famously unreliable. I suggest you use a userform instead.

Comment: Also in first method You must delete "Exit Sub" to make it works as expected.

Comment: hi folks sorry for late response. The message box doesn't disappear as it suppose too after certain amount of time. Going with Rory advice I think I'll give it a miss anyway